# Dimensions added using MeasureIt addon not appearing in final render

Tags: rendering, add-on, dimensions

How do I make the dimensions added using MeasureIt appear in a final render?

[image: the dimenison of .95m doesnt appear in my final render]

Comment: Your expectations are wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the *View* menu of the viewport area of interest, you can choose *Viewport Render Image* option.

Disabling overlays [image] keps the measureIt overlays, so you can use that to your advantage:

[image]

---

In order to get your measurements rendered, all you would have to do is:

1. Click on the <kbd>Render</kbd> button in the *Render* panel which is going to render your measurements as a separate image based on the active camera
2. Open up a new *Compositor* window or just switch the workspace to *Compositing*, add an *Image* as well as an *Alpha Over* node
3. Set the image for *Image* node to generated image by the *MeasureIt* add-on
4. Plug your rendering into the upper socket and the generated image into the foreground (lower) socket of the *Alpha Over* node

[image]

Also have a look into the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/3d_view/measureit.html.

Comment: the manual is very vague. I'm just trying to figure out what the Annotation button does and it is not even mentioned in the manual :-(

Comment: @Blunder I don't know, I think it's a good question to be asked on its own.